# How can I write a matlab script for this equation?

Tags: matlab, equation

I have the following output in `matlab`:

```
   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   27.9464   27.4044   31.4643   31.9374   22.5832
   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   22.5832
   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   22.5832
   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   22.5832
   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   22.5832
   31.9374   31.9374   31.9374   27.6586   27.6586   31.9374   31.9374   22.5832
   22.5832   22.5832   22.5832   15.9687   15.9687   22.5832   22.5832   15.9687
```

For that data and and for **each** value shown, I want to calculate the following equation which acts as a normalization that makes the values range from `0-255` since I have other data similar to that with larger values that I also want to calculate.

The equation is as follows:

```
255 x (original value - 0) / (maximum value in matrix - minimum value in matrix)
```

How can I perform this in `matlab`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the data in matrix `A`...

```
255 * A / (max(A(:)) - min(A(:)))
```